# Working with layer variables in rule-based styling query builder in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, pyqgis-3, expression

I want to make an "Action" in QGIS 3.16 that enables me quickly to style features I select in the rule-based styling.

The action code below produces a string of the selected features, and saves them in a `layer` variable.

```py
layer_id = '[%@layer_id%]'
layer = QgsProject().instance().mapLayer(layer_id)

list = []

for feature in layer.selectedFeatures():
    list.append(feature['myfeature'])

string1 = str(list)[1:-1]
string2 = "(" + string1 + ")"

QgsExpressionContextUtils.setLayerVariable(layer,'variablename',string2)
```

This piece of codes works well and produces a string like this example:

```
(1072566, 1072375, 9400438, 1072569, 3241157, 1072376)
```

In the query builder, I want to make a filter based on the variable, like this:

```
"myfeature" IN (@variablename)
```

Unfortunately, this **doesn't** work.

When I test the filter, it tells me that no features are returned.

But if I copy the output string, it works:

```
"myfeature" IN (1072566, 1072375, 9400438, 1072569, 3241157, 1072376)
```

and when I only enter

```
@variablename
```

I can see in the bottom of the Query Builder window, that it returns the correct string to use in an IN-clause.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Instead of @variablename try to enter var(‚variablename‘).

Comment: If I enter var(‚variablename‘), the query builder wont accept the parsing. 
If I enter var('variablename') I unfortunately still experience the same issue.

Comment: Actually, it won't accept the syntax unless I put paratheses around everything I put after the IN-clause. I wonder if the SQL-like statement excludes the use of qgis variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are using this expression
`"myfeature" IN (1072566, 1072375, 9400438, 1072569, 3241157, 1072376)`
you are comparing an integer to an array of integer that's why it works. When you are using this expression
`"myfeature" IN ("variablename")`
you are comparing an integer to a string, so it wont work. You need to create an array of string and convert your integer as a string.

You should create your string without parenthesis like this
`'1072566, 1072375, 9400438, 1072569, 3241157, 1072376'`.
And then create an array based on this string in the query builder with the function [string_to_array](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/fr/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#string-to-array), `string_to_array("variablename", ', ')`. Your array will look like this `['1072566', '1072375', '9400438', '1072569', '3241157', '1072376']`, it's an array of string.

`"myfeature"` needs to be a string aswell, you can use the function [to_string](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/fr/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#to-string), `to_string("myfeature")`

Finally, to compare an array and a value you can use the function [array_contains](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/fr/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#array-contains),`array_contains(string_to_array("variablename", ', '),to_string("myfeature"))`

Comment: This works excellent! 
In this case where the action produces a layer variable, the "variablename" just needs to be replaced by @variablename, so filter query will be:

array_contains(string_to_array(@variablename, ', '),to_string("myfeature"))